# regex not matching pattern

Tags: python, regex

Anyone can help me to understand why this regex `\(\w+[^config]\)` matches `(epam_contractor_net)` , `(ctmain1_soasta_eucap1_coresys)` and not `(epam_contractor_soasta_web_svc)` in the below string?

```
config term

fw1-ravpn-lab-lon(config)# no object-group service epam_contractor_soasta_web_s$m_contractor_soasta_web_sv                         cno object-group service epam_contractor_soasta_web_$
Removing object-group (epam_contractor_soasta_web_svc) not allowed, it is being used.

fw1-ravpn-lab-lon(config)# no  service-object tcp destination eq www
                                       ^
ERROR: % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

fw1-ravpn-lab-lon(config)# no object-group network epam_contractor_net
Removing object-group (epam_contractor_net) not allowed, it is being used.

fw1-ravpn-lab-lon(config)# no object-group network ctmain1_soasta_eucap1_coresy$ain1_soasta_eucap1_coresys                         no object-group network ctmain1_soasta_eucap1_cores$
Removing object-group (ctmain1_soasta_eucap1_coresys) not allowed, it is being used.

fw1-ravpn-lab-lon(config)# end

fw1-ravpn-lab-lon#
```

Comment: Well, I'd start with the fact that `[^config]` means "not any of the characters c, o, n, f, i, or g," which probably isn't what you intended.

Comment: correct. I want to match `config` as whole word

Comment: Can you show the code where you compile the regex string? I've put your regex into regexr and it matches all three of those strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern `\(\w+[^config]\)` will exclude anything ending with any of the characters in `config` (`c`, `o`, `n`, `f`, `i`, `g`), not the string `config` itself. This means if you had a value of `(i_end_in_c)` it would also not be matched (because it ends with a `c`). The same would apply for `(i_end_in_o)` or `(i_end_in_n)` etc.

This is the same reason that `(epam_contractor_soasta_web_svc)` is not found - because it ends in a `c`.

You should use a negative lookahead instead:

```
\((?!config)\w+\)
```

The above will not match any string starting with `config`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have means one or more word characters `\w+` and you specify that the very last char shouldn't be any of `c, o, n, f, i, or g`. However, the last char in `epam_contractor_soasta_web_svc` is `c`. Hence, it doesn't match this string.